# a script for accounts that had only deposits and no withdrawals presented in the month of February 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a rookie in SQL with my script because I need is to get the accounts had only deposits and no withdrawals presented in February, but I can't think of a script that can get the query I need, try a distinct, group by, but does not show what I need:

The tables in order:

**CuentasBancaria**

[image: cuentasbancaria]

**Retiros/Withdrawals**

[image]

**Depositos/Deposits**

[image]

and i tried with this script:

```
DECLARE @FechaDeterminado VARCHAR(10)
SET @FechaDeterminado = '2016-02-01'

IF EXISTS(SELECT a.FechaMovimiento FROM [dbo].[Retiros] a 
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] b
                    ON a.CuentaId = b.CuentaId 
                    WHERE a.FechaMovimiento >= @FechaDeterminado)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('No hay clientes sin retiros en el mes',16,1)
END

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT a.FechaMovimiento FROM [dbo].[Retiros] a 
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] b
                    ON a.CuentaId = b.CuentaId 
                    WHERE a.FechaMovimiento >= @FechaDeterminado)
BEGIN 
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] a
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Depositos] b
        ON a.CuentaId = b.CuentaId 
        WHERE FechaMovimiento >= @FechaDeterminado
END
```

but it is not the correct... as it shows the results when no withdrawals, but shows fail when at least there was a retreat, what I want is to achieve a script or query to get customers who have only made no deposits and withdrawal in the month

Comment: Use left join on deposit table and inner join on withdrawal table.

Comment: hmmm can you show me the script ?? i'm very rookie in SQL... can you help me ?

Comment: `select *
from accounts a
left join deposit d on d.userid = a.id
inner join withdrawal w on w.userid = a.id` add the date condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `if` for this.  You can do this with a `WHERE` clause:

```
select cb.*
from CuentasBancaria cb
where not exists (select 1
                  from retiros r
                  where cb.CuentaId = r.CuentaId and
                        r.FechaMovimiento >= '2016-02-01' and
                        r.FechaMovimiento < '2016-03-01' 
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from depositors d
              where cb.CuentaId = d.CuentaId and
                    d.FechaMovimiento >= '2016-02-01' and
                    d.FechaMovimiento < '2016-03-01' 
             );
```